# JQuery FancyBox, Prepend function and <a href> tag does not work in IE 7 and 8..(other browsers work ok functionally)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, href

I have wrote a code that includes jquery to display fancybox when a thumbnail is clicked, and the prepend function to add  tag to display magnifier tag on the top of image thumbnail (top of layer). What was strange that when the webpage is rendered in IE, the thumbnails seem "unclickable" (not showing hand cursor nor provide link functionality) thus could not show or run fancybox script in render. The other browser such as Firefox, Chrome works perfect with these three things running at the same time.

Here is a piece of code in html:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>

                <title>Private Functions /title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

                <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />   
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="css/ui.totop.css" /> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" type="text/css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>     
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>      
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>  
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Proxima_Nova_Rg_400-Proxima_Nova_Rg_700-Proxima_Nova_Rg_italic_400-Proxima_Nova_Rg_italic_700.font.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/BernhardMod_BT_400-BernhardMod_BT_700-BernhardMod_BT_italic_700.font.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Liberation_Serif_400-Liberation_Serif_700-Liberation_Serif_italic_400-Liberation_Serif_italic_700.font.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Gotham_Book_325-Gotham_Medium_350-Gotham_Book_italic_325-Gotham_Medium_italic_350.font.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Gotham_Light_300-Gotham_Bold_400-Gotham_Light_italic_300-Gotham_Bold_italic_400.font.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Gotham_Thin_250-Gotham_Bold_400-Gotham_Thin_italic_250-Gotham_Bold_italic_400.font.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
                <!--[if IE 7]>

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="css/ie7.css" />  
                <![endif]-->
                <script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <!-- easing plugin ( optional ) -->
                <script src="js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <!-- UItoTop plugin -->
                <script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    Cufon.replace('#controls .left, #controls .right, #footer .wrap', { fontFamily: 'Proxima Nova Rg' }); 
                    Cufon.replace('#nav2 li, #nav2 li a, .sidebar .menu ul li', { fontFamily: 'Gotham Book' }); 
                    Cufon.replace('#nav2 li a.selected', { fontFamily: 'Gotham Medium' }); 
                    Cufon.replace('.content h2', { fontFamily: 'Gotham Thin' }); 
                    Cufon.replace('.content p', { fontFamily: 'Liberation Serif' });
                    jQuery(function(){
                    /*
                    var defaults = {
                        containerID: 'moccaUItoTop', // fading element id
                        containerHoverClass: 'moccaUIhover', // fading element hover class
                        scrollSpeed: 1200,
                        easingType: 'linear' 
                    };
                    */

                    $("<span></span").prependTo('.thumbnails a');

                    $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

                });         
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    /*
                        Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
                    */

                    $(".thumbnails a").fancybox();


                });
            </script>



            </head>

        <body>

            <div class="content">
                        <div class="banner"><img src="images/history-banner.jpg" alt="History of 333 Collins Street Melbourne" title="Melbourne's Most Exclusive Address - History"/></div>
                        <h2>Fusce nisi 333 Collins for your private function</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In lacinia dolor orci. Nulla tempus faucibus velit quis euismod. Mauris nec tellus sapien. Nullam bibendum, augue sed eleifend fermentum, neque orci pulvinar nunc, quis laoreet enim arcu ac ipsum.</p>

        <p>Sed sit amet lorem ipsum, ac ornare tortor. Donec non mauris consectetur nulla convallis venenatis. Morbi facilisis molestie nisi, et scelerisque arcu pulvinar sit amet. In vehicula eros in nisl dictum iaculis.</p>

                    <div class="thumbnails">
                        <a href="gallery/private-functions/private-function-2.jpg" title="Private Function 1"><img src="images/private-function-1.jpg" width="220" height="122" alt="Private Function 1"/></a>
                        <a href="gallery/private-functions/private-function-1.jpg" title="Private Function 2"><img src="images/private-function-2.jpg" width="220" height="122" alt="Private Function 2"/></a>
                        <a href="gallery/private-functions/private-function-3.jpg" title="Private Function 3"><img src="images/private-function-3.jpg" width="220" height="122" alt="Private Function 3" class="norightmargin"/></a>


                    </div>



                 </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

and piece of css:

```
        /** -----CONTENT --------------------*/

    .content { padding-bottom: 3em; float:right; width:703px; height: auto; margin-right: 76px;  }
    .banner{height:180px; width: 700px; margin-bottom:47px;}
    .content h1{margin-bottom:28px; font-size:25pt;color: #000000;}
    .content h2{margin-bottom:28px; font-size:25pt;color: #000000;}
    .content p{margin-bottom:36px; font-size:13pt; line-height: 25pt;}
    .content p cufon{ margin-bottom:7px;}
    .content .thumbnails img{
        border:none; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:20px;z-index:-10;
    }
    .content .thumbnails img.norightmargin{
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .content .thumbnails a span{
        width:220px; position: absolute;
        height: 122px;

    }
    .content .thumbnails a span:hover{
        background: url(images/rollover-magnifier.png) no-repeat;
    }
```

I appreciate if there is any recommended rectification solution to enable image thumbnails to be clickable as well as popping up using fancybox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this part of your css is creating the conflict

```
.content .thumbnails a span{
        width:220px; position: absolute;
        height: 122px;

    }
```

it seems like the anchor falls behind the absolute positioned "prepended" `span`

For instance if you have something like

```
.content .thumbnails a {
        width:240px;

    }
```

you would see than only the last 20px of the anchor would be clickable. Of course, we are tlaking about IE here.